# Should I use remote filtering/sorting/grouping when using buffered store?If yes, why?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to understand the difference between remote and local sorting/filtering/grouping.
Can I use them without any problem? I would like to use them on an "unlimited" table with buffering.

Any information is appreciated, because actually I'm implementing their remote version but is costing me time. It would be better if I can use local version of them.

What are the advantages/disadvantages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can use local sorting and filtering with the unlimited store. I mean, you can do this, but your users will not like results.

Yes, making remote sort and filtering is a it trickier, but it's all very doable. We use the in our projects forthe stores we can't afford to load completely. If you have any specific questions I would be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually implemented them and they work quite nice. I don't understand if I must implement remote grouping or it doesn't matter (I use it).

Comment: I guess... We don't use grouping in our application, but I think if you use it - you have to do this on the server side.